# Linq query to get person visited zones of current day

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api, azure-sql-database

I am working on web api with Entity framework as object-relational mapping (ORM) framework for ADO.NET. I need to write a linq query which should return most recent 5 zones traveled by a person.
[image]

My table with respective columns is depicted in the attached image. I am using azure sql database as my back-end storage, from the above data ***i need to get top 5 zone_id list as [4,2,3,2,1] by using linq query***. client may request to get zones list with in specific range of **stime**.

Comment: What you try so far? And what you mean _i need to get top 5 zone_id_ ? What is _top_? . You cen use linq like : `yourTable.Where(l=>l.stime>= DT1 && l.stime<= DT2).OrderByDescending(x => x.stime).Select(l=>l.zone_id).Take(5).ToList();` - this return top 5 (newest) beetwen DT1 and DT2

Comment: If i have total 10 zones in my area with zone ids as 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10. If a person traveled for current day like the sequence 1,2,2,3,4,4,1,5,6,6,6,3 within given range of stime then first i need to filter the zone ids as 1,2,3,4,1,5,6,3 then i need to return 1,2,3,4,1(top 5) as final list.

Comment: So before `.Take(5)` use `.Distinct()` . Like : `yourTable.Where(l=>l.stime>= DT1 && l.stime<= DT2).OrderByDescending(x => x.stime).Select(l=>l.zone_id).Distinct().Take(5).ToList();`

Comment: if i use Distinct it will returns as 1,2,3,4,5 but i need to know overall path for this i need 1,2,3,4,1 as final list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you are asking but to get the list of zone-Id would be something like:

```
var zoneIds = data.Select(z => z.zone_id).Distinct();
```

This will get you the individual zone ids. (The distinct removes duplicate zone id entries).

If you want to filter by date it would be something like:

```
var zoneIds = data.Where(z => z.stime > [lowerDateTimeBound] && z.stime < [upperDateTimeBound]).Select(z => z.zone_id).Distinct();
```

For most recent 5 I would use:

```
var zoneIds = data.OrderByDescending(z => z.stime).Select(z => z.zone_id).Distinct().Take(5);
```

If you want to get all zones without removing duplicates remove the .Distinct() call. And to get more result change the `Take(x)` number. Result should be as follows:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4] // With distinct
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3] // Without distinct
```

UPDATE: based on your comments.

Use this to get the list of zone Ids:

```
var zoneIds = data.OrderByDescending(z => z.stime).Select(z => z.zone_id).ToList();
var zoneIdsArray = zoneIds.ToArray();
for(int c = 1; c < zoneIdsArray.Count(); c ++)
{
    if (zoneIdsArray[c].zone_id == zoneIdsArray[c-1].zone_id)
    {
        zoneIds.Remove(zoneIdsArray[c]);
    }
}

var last5Zones = zoneIds.Select(z => z.zone_id).ToList().Take(5);
```

The resulting last5Zones list should have the correct list of last 5 zones (according to what I think you are looking for from your comments)

Comment: Thank u very much for ur quick replay, i re-defined my question, please  refere it at M. Wiśnicki comments section.

Comment: @KrishnarjunBanoth it looks like you are trying to remove consecutive duplicates.  The code still applies just cycle through the array and remove consecutive duplicates.  See updated answer.

Comment: Actually that is what my major problem I don't know how to remove consecutive duplicates by using linq query. Will you please help me

Comment: Thank u very much it had given me a path to rethink about my process to solve my problem

Comment: No problem, just remember to use a separate array to loop through and not the collection you are modifying (removing from) or you will come across errors

Comment: Hi DarthJam, Thanks for your help, i need some more help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43188596/how-to-call-a-local-method-from-the-linq-query please refer this link for my problem, same problem can we achieve through views?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear about what the expected result is. You state that you want the 5 most recent zones the person traveled in, which, according to your picture should result in **[4,2,3,3,2]** however you state the result should be **[4,2,3,2,1]** which is not in chronological order.

Nevertheless, the LINQ statement you would use to filter the data by the record's 5 most recently traveled zones would be:

```
int[] mostRecentZones = _ctx.OrderByDescending(x=>x.stime).Take(5).Select(x=>x.zone_id).ToArray();
```

Assuming '_ctx' is the name of you DBContext object and 'stime' is a DateTime object and 'zone_id' is an integer field.